# I am getting the following Error: no matching function for call to ‘A::A()’?

Tags: c++, class

I defined a Class, whose constructor consist of 3 integer arguments.

```
class A{
int a,b,c;
A(int x,int y,int z){
a=x;
b=y;
c=z;
}
};
```

Now, another class is defined as follows

```
class B{
A a;
B(A x){
a=x;
}
};
```

The error I am getting is

```
Error:  no matching function for call to ‘A::A()’
```

Can somebody help me in defining these two classes ?

Comment: You must _initialise_ that `A` member. You can't just assign to it, because it cannot be default constructed. Look up "member initialisation lists".

Comment: I wonder why such questions are so often downvoted. Everyone starts small, and from a complete beginner's POV, the question is justified, especially if all your previous experience was with Java, where a similar piece of code would compile and work just fine. It has copy-n-pastable, correctly formatted code and a clear error message. What's wrong with that?

Comment: @ChristianHackl I think because we tell people over and over again that you can't learn C++ by just winging it. You need to read a book and OP obviously failed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not implementing constructors correctly. You need to use a [member initialization list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list):

```
class B {
  A a_;
public:
  B(const A& a) : a_(a) {}
};
```

otherwise the member `a_` is going to be default constructed before the body of the constructor is entered. Your class `A` does not have a default constructor so this leads to an error.